# Why the Python for loop for agg func does not work?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Why the Python using loop for agg func does not work but the code above the for loop which is done for each element individually works

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                       [4, 5, 6],
                       [7, 8, 9],
                       [10,11,12]],
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    
    cols=['A', 'B', 'C']
    
    a=[]
    
    #a.append(test.agg(**{'A'+'_sum' : ('A','sum'), 'A'+'_min' : ('A','min'), 'A' + "_max" : ('A', "max"), 'A' + "_mean" : ('A', "mean")}))
    
    #a.append(test.agg(**{'B'+'_sum' : ('B','sum'), 'B'+'_min' : ('B','min'), 'B' + "_max" : ('B', "max"), 'B' + "_mean" : ('B', "mean")}))
    
    #a.append(test.agg(**{'C'+'_sum' : ('C','sum'), 'C'+'_min' : ('C','min'), 'C' + "_max" : ('C', "max"), 'C' + "_mean" : ('C', "mean")}))
    
    for col in cols:
    
          a.append(test.agg(**{col + "_first" : (col, "first"),
    
                col + "_min" : (col, "min"),
    
                col + "_max" : (col, "max"),
    
                col + "_mean" : (col, "mean")
                }
            )
        )
    
    a
```

Comment: The commented-out code does not try to use `_first`, but the uncommented code does.

Comment: What is your intended output?  A new dataframe with those aggregrations?

Comment: @ScottHunter you are correct, thanks. If I remove _first part in loop, it works. But is first not a func? I could not find a list of funcs that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is, most likely, never the best idea in pandas. Here is a pseudo answer, while not exactly your 'a' output, it will give you a df to play with that has the data.

```
# Describe will give you most of your desired data.
desc_df = test.describe()
# Create a summed df to use with .concat()
sum_df = pd.DataFrame([test.sum(axis=0)])
# Name the row.
sum_df.index = ['sum']
# Concat them.
final_df = pd.concat([desc_df, sum_df])
# Example to a different type, since yours was a list.
final_df.to_dict()
```